Are there ways to improve the following code?
I have the following function that returns one of several functions along with their derivative for training neural networks.
Can this function be improved and made more pythonic in any way?
Are there other things like reducing the redundancy of the list etc.?
Could a better way be to instead enclose the inner functions inside a class?
Note: I am not looking to optimize the computational aspects of the functions.
import numpy as np


def get_activation_fn_with_deriv(fn_name):
    """ Returns function objects for activation function and its derivative.

    Returns function objects for the specified activation function and its derivative function.

    Args:
        fn_name: Name of the activation function.
    
    Returns:
        (fn, fn_deriv): A tuple of the activation function and its derivative function.
    
    Raises:
        ValueError: If an unavailable activation function is retrieved.
    
    Examples:
        >>> relu, relu_deriv = activation_fn_with_deriv('relu')
        >>> relu(np.array([1, -1, 2.3]))
        array([1. , 0. , 2.3])
    """

    available_fn = ['identity', 'relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh']

    match fn_name.lower():
        case 'identity':
            def identity(x):
                return x
            
            def identity_deriv(x):
                return np.ones(x.shape)
            
            return identity, identity_deriv
        
        case 'relu':
            def relu(x):
                return np.maximum(x, 0.0)

            def relu_deriv(x):
                return np.where(x >= 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

            return relu, relu_deriv
        
        case 'sigmoid':
            def sigmoid(x):
                return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

            def sigmoid_deriv(x):
                sigmoid_x = sigmoid(x)
                return sigmoid_x * (1 - sigmoid_x)
            
            return sigmoid, sigmoid_deriv
        
        case 'tanh':
            def tanh(x):
                exp_2x = np.exp(2 * x)
                return (exp_2x - 1) / (exp_2x + 1)

            def tanh_deriv(x):
                return 1 - tanh(x) ** 2
            
            return tanh, tanh_deriv

        case _:
            raise ValueError(f'Specified activation function not available. Choose from - {[name.lower() for name in available_fn]}.')


Defining functions inside case statements is weird, and you don't really need named functions for your use case anyway as you don't call them by name. The answer posted uses lambdas, which makes more sense in this case.

@Selcuk The answer seems good. But I think using the lambdas is making it cryptic. Anyone reading the code might find it confusing. Also, using lambdas is restricting computational efficiency. For example in my implementation I cache the value of np.exp(2 * x) in a variable to use it later at 2 places.

Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [codereview.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

@tripleee I am unable to delete this post.

import numpy as np


def get_activation_fn_with_deriv(fn_name):
    """Returns function objects for activation function and its derivative.

    Returns function objects for the specified activation function and its derivative function.

    Args:
        fn_name: Name of the activation function.

    Returns:
        (fn, fn_deriv): A tuple of the activation function and its derivative function.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If an unavailable activation function is retrieved.

    Examples:
        >>> relu, relu_deriv = activation_fn_with_deriv('relu')
        >>> relu(np.array([1, -1, 2.3]))
        array([1. , 0. , 2.3])
    """

    try:
        return _activation_fn_with_deriv_dict[fn_name.lower()]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Specified activation function not available. Choose from - {list(_activation_fn_with_deriv_dict)}."
        )


def _identity(x):
    return x


def _identity_deriv(x):
    return np.ones(x.shape)


def _relu(x):
    return np.maximum(x, 0.0)


def _relu_deriv(x):
    return np.where(x >= 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)


def _sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))


def _sigmoid_deriv(x):
    sigmoid_x = _sigmoid(x)
    return sigmoid_x * (1 - sigmoid_x)


def _tanh(x):
    exp_2x = np.exp(2 * x)
    return (exp_2x - 1) / (exp_2x + 1)


def _tanh_deriv(x):
    return 1 - _tanh(x) ** 2


_activation_fn_with_deriv_dict = {
    "identity": (_identity, _identity_deriv),
    "relu": (_relu, _relu_deriv),
    "sigmoid": (_sigmoid, _sigmoid_deriv),
    "tanh": (_tanh, _tanh_deriv),
}

Key points:

Make those functions global. Name them with a prefix underscore if you don't want them to be directly used outside the module. Using an inner function normally indicates that some local variables are involved, or the function itself has very limited usage. It is not the case here.

Predefine the mapping and reuse it. Although creating a dict every time may be cheap, it is still unnecessary overhead.

There is no need to manually concatenate dict keys. A more PYTHONIC way would be just to wrap a dict with list.


EDIT
Adjust function order to emphasize the entrance function.

Great points. But I have a question w.r.t defining the functions as global. If the list of functions were to grow. Then the get_activation_fn_with_deriv() function which is really what a person using the code should be concerned with will be pushed way down the file and it will be hard to find. Any comments on that?

You may move get_activation_fn_with_deriv up at the top of the file and move other stuff (including the mapping object) down.

Edited with a different order which may address your concern.

import numpy as np

def get_activation_fn_with_deriv(fn_name):
    """Returns function objects for the specified activation function and its derivative.

    Args:
        fn_name (str): Name of the activation function.
    
    Returns:
        tuple: A tuple of the activation function and its derivative function.
    
    Raises:
        ValueError: If an unavailable activation function is retrieved.
    """

    available_fn = {
        'identity': (np.array, lambda x: np.ones(x.shape)),
        'relu': (np.maximum, lambda x: np.where(x >= 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
        'sigmoid': (lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x)), lambda x: sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))),
        'tanh': (lambda x: (np.exp(2 * x) - 1) / (np.exp(2 * x) + 1), lambda x: 1 - tanh(x) ** 2)
    }

    try:
        fn, fn_deriv = available_fn[fn_name.lower()]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(f'Specified activation function "{fn_name}" not available. Choose from - {", ".join(available_fn.keys())}.')

    return fn, fn_deriv

